# p4 edit openes few files

Tags: submit, perforce, edit

I have a problem with "p4 edit" command, it opens two files for me which creates mess when I try to submit my changes.
Here is example output of p4 edit:

p4 edit //depot/project/myproject/Test.java

//depot/project/myproject/Test.java#24 - currently opened for edit
//depot/project/myproject/Test.java#20 - currently opened for edit

I can not figure out why this happens, only idea I have is to check if I have wrong client specification, but it is correct. I map one depot folder to exactly one client folder.

Regards, Victor

Comment: From the output you show, 'p4 edit' seems to be working properly. You asked it to open a file for edit, it responded by telling you the file is already opened for edit. Use 'p4 opened' to see what files you have opened. After opening a file for edit, you may proceed to make modifications to the file, then use 'p4 submit' to submit those changes back to the server.

Comment: More specifically, perforce responded by telling you that you have an older version open for edit.  You have version #20 open for edit and you are trying to open a later version (#24) for edit.

Comment: Problem I have is I do not understand why p4 working with two versions of my file, when I do p4 revert it reverts two versions as well:

//depot/project/myproject/Test.java#20  - was edit, reverted
//depot/project/myproject/Test.java#24  - was edit, reverted

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have somehow got two copies of Test.java mapped to different local files in your Perforce workspace.  To test this theory, run

```
p4 have //depot/project/myproject/Test.java
```

Then, if you do have two versions in different directories, run

```
p4 client
```

and edit the paths in your client so that you only map //depot/project/myproject/ to a single local directory.